# How can I keep *all* environment vars for a specific command in sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

I have a script that sets several environment variables and then finally calls another script using sudo.

The script run with sudo must be able to pick up those variables, and I'm not always going to be certain what those variables are.

Is there a way of configuring this sudoers entry to allow the command complete access to the callers env vars?

```
%deploy ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/build.sh
```

When I run the sudo command from my script:

```
sudo -E build.sh "$@"
```

I get:

```
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment
```

Googling around I've only found ways to preserve specific variables and not just everything.

Comment: What Unix are we talking about here? Different Unixes have different sudo implementations.

Comment: Note that allowing users to call a shell script as any user without imposing restrictions on the environment is equivalent to giving them super user access.

Comment: Agree with Stephane, what you're trying to do is a bad idea from a security standpoint! User's can play games and put things into their path and elevate the credentials that this script is being run as.

Comment: Thanks, I changed how my script works a bit so that it doesn't rely on env vars to run.. instead it reads a config file. Seemed more sane. I did have a feeling I was doing something a little bit dodgy..

Comment: Use a config file, preferably in a location that non-root users can't get at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing the first answer and still getting `sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment`, I decided to look around for a better solution.

After a bit of testing, I found that the option that matters is `setenv`.

```
Defaults!/bin/build.sh setenv
```

To make it a little more secure, we can add a couple settings:

```
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
Defaults!/bin/build.sh setenv,env_reset,env_delete+=PATH,env_delete+=LD_PRELOAD,env_delete+=LD_LIBRARY_PATH,env_delete+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK,env_delete+=PYTHONPATH,env_delete+=PERL5LIB
%deploy  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/build.sh *
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow users in the `deploy` group to run any command with almost any environment variable:

```
Defaults:%deploy !env_reset,env_delete-=PYTHONPATH,env_delete-=PERL5LIB
%deploy ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

Run `sudo -V` to see which variables are deleted.

There is little point in restricting the command if you allow the user to preserve all environment variables, as this is likely to allow the user to run arbitrary code via some variable.

If you've carefully reviewed your script and you're sure that you have an exhaustive list of environment variables that need to be removed, you can specify that these environment variables should be deleted and all others should be kept.

```
Defaults!/bin/build.sh !env_reset,env_delete+=DANGEROUS_VAR
%deploy ALL = (ALL) /bin/build.sh
```

Comment: If the `sudo` implementation provides it, I would always prefer to define a whitelist using the `env_keep` option. And this list should definitely not include something like `PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD` or `PERL5LIB`.

Comment: @Dubu The whole point of this question was to allow unknown variables to get through, so not whitelisting. Allowing arbitrary variables (even `PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD`, whatever) to go through is not a security hole if you allow any command to be run: it's only a security hole if you want to restrict the command, because a lot of variables allow working around the command restriction.

Answer (score -1):

Run `sudo visudo` and comment out the two lines shown below. Commenting out only `env_reset` does not work

```
#Defaults       env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
#Defaults       secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to recommend a solution that causes all environment variables to be preserved for *all* invocations of `sudo` by *all* users.

Comment: That's a subjective statement. I am the only user of my machine, don't download untrusted content, and I'm well versed in Linux CLI. There's no reason for me to have training wheels on my system that just slow me down. That being said, if I set up a multi-user system, I'd have a limited list of sudoers, and I'd make sure they're well versed so that they don't need training wheels.