# keep aliases when I use sudo bash

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a Centos 5.5 server that has my own alias commands for my account. When I do `sudo bash` I can still use those aliases, I didn't have to add the aliases to the root's `.bashrc`.

I have another server that is Centos 6.5. But when I execute `sudo bash`, it will not use my aliases of the user that I'm logged in as. Does anyone know where I configure it to include the aliases of the user I am logged into when I use `sudo bash`?

Comment: I think aliases are inherited via the environment, so maybe the answer here will work: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92998/how-can-i-keep-all-environment-vars-for-a-specific-command-in-sudo?rq=1

Comment: The 5.5 one probably preserved $HOME from the caller, while 6.5 doesn't. See `sudo sudo -V` output and `env_keep` in the sudoers man page.

Comment: Thanks Barmar and Stephane. Both your answer pointed me in the right direction. I had to set the following in sudoers:
`Defaults    !always_set_home` and `Defaults    !env_reset`
`

Answer (score 14):

Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

From the bash manual

> Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as
>   the first word of a simple command. The shell maintains a list of
>   aliases that may be set and unset with the alias and unalias builtin
>   commands.
>
> The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see
>   if it has an alias. If so, that word is replaced by the text of the
>   alias. The characters ‘/’, ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘=’ and any of the shell
>   metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an
>   alias name. The replacement text may contain any valid shell input,
>   including shell metacharacters. The first word of the replacement text
>   is tested for aliases, but a word that is identical to an alias being
>   expanded is not expanded a second time. This means that one may alias
>   ls to "ls -F", for instance, and Bash does not try to recursively
>   expand the replacement text. If the last character of the alias value
>   is a space or tab character, then the next command word following the
>   alias is also checked for alias expansion.

So Bash only checks the first word of a command for an alias, any words after that are not checked. That means in a command like sudo ll, only the first word (sudo) is checked by bash for an alias, ll is ignored. We can tell bash to check the next word after the alias (i.e sudo) by adding a space to the end of the alias value.

Comment: Works for zsh as well just fine. Thank you!

Comment: This just allows to use aliases in the `sudo` command, e.g. `sudo some_alias ...`, but what OP is asking is how to make aliases defined for his own user work after he switches to another user using `sudo`. Let's say I have `some_alias` defined. When I `sudo` to `root` using `sudo su`, a new environment is created and that alias is not defined there. There's the `-E` parameter of the `sudo` command which should export the environment but it looks like aliases are not part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo -E`, which will export your environment.

Comment: does not include aliases (tested on Ubuntu 16.04.1)

Comment: It's working but only as `sudo -E bash`. When used with `su` as `sudo -E su`, the stuff defined in user's `.bashrc` (aliases, prompt, etc.) are not preserved, even though it looks like environment variables are preserved in both cases. I'm not sure how exactly this is working.

Comment: It doesn't preserve aliases for me, not even for `sudo -E bash`. My aliases are defined in `~/.bashrc`.